# Does the magnitude of the induced current change?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

The coil is circular and is closed, meaning that current can flow through it. So this enters a region of magnetic field where with time, more and more magnetic field lines cross it.

My question is, since the magnetic flux linkage increases through the coil, does that mean that the induced current increases in magnitude because it's magnetic field must get stronger/greater to oppose the more magnetic flux going through it?

Comment: A diagram might make your question more clear. What's the mechanism you have in mind for increasing the flux linkage? For example, are you asking what happens if the source of magentic field gets stronger or weaker, or are you asking what happens if we change the geometry of the coil or increase the number of turns?

Comment: exactly, this is how the current source does work against the induced current so that the coil's energy in the induced magnetic field increases and equals the increment of work done by the source with its larger "bias" current..

Comment: @The Photon, by increasing magnetic flux linkage I mean that the coil (closed) cuts more magnetic field lines with time

Comment: @hyportnex, so when the coil cuts more magnetic field lines, the induced current becomes larger and hence it has more magnetic field lines, right?

Comment: What's the load? If the coil is open circuited, then there's 0 current, despite the induced voltage (aka emf).

Comment: The coil is circular and is closed, meaning that current can flow through it. So this enters a region of magnetic field where with time, more and more magnetic field lines cross it.

Comment: Please include a diagram in the question post so that readers can understand the question without reading the comments (which might be cleaned up by the mods at any time).